# JComboBox does not appear in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jcomponent

```
public void preferencesScreen(){
    preferencesScreen = new JPanel();
    preferencesScreen.setLayout(null);
    preferencesScreen.setBounds(0,0,500,1000);

    backButton = new JButton("<-");
    slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL,0,100,50);

    restrictionDropdown = new JComboBox<>(user.getPreferences().allergies);
    restrictionDropdown.setLocation(200,300);
    restrictionDropdown.setSize(100,100);
    restrictionDropdown.addActionListener(actionListener);
    restrictionDropdown.setEditable(true);
    preferencesScreen.add(restrictionDropdown);




    slider.setMajorTickSpacing(5);
    slider.setPaintTicks(true);

    backButton.setBounds(20,30,50,40);
    slider.setBounds(300,140,160,50);

    backButton.addActionListener(actionListener);

    preferencesScreen.add(backButton);
    preferencesScreen.add(slider);

    frame.setVisible(true);



}
```

The restrictionDropdown will not appear on the screen along with the other two components. The class I am working out of extends JComponent. Additionally, when I try to add the combobox to the frame directly, it appears and takes up the entire frame despite setting a size and location.

I've tried changing the border layout to flow, I've tried using setSize and setLocation instead of setBounds, I tried changing the order of the method calls to the combobox, I tried declaring the combobox inside the given method. I tried using the frame instead of the panel itself(see above). None of these except for the last thing caused the combobox to appear

Comment: Nowhere in this code do you add the panel to the frame (`frame.add(preferencesScreen); frame.pack();`)

Comment: @ryvantage i repaint the frame,call the method and add the panel in an action listener, i can provide more if its important

Comment: it is best to have a [mre] - by posted code it cannot appear. Also using a null layout manager is easily a cause for errors and should not be used (that is, use layout managers)

Comment: null layout and hard-coded sizing/positioning is __wrong__ - instead learn to find and use a layoutManager that suits your requirements

Comment: Respectfully disagree with @kleopatra. I have many apps in production through a decade of development that use `AbsoluteLayout` from Netbeans' GUI builder (Matisse). Functionality is king. Coding standards are important but not preeminent.

Comment: Especially given that Swing is an aged-out API. You should already be exercising caution about building production apps with Swing.

Comment: Lastly, the best swing layout is `MigLayout` (https://www.miglayout.com/) and I haven't seen any activity in maintaining/supporting that layout in years.

Answer (score -1):

I made a [Minimal, Reproducible Example™](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with your code trying to imitate what I think you're trying to accomplish:

```
public class NewClass1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NewClass1 newClass = new NewClass1();
        newClass.frame = new JFrame();
        newClass.preferencesScreen();
        newClass.frame.add(newClass.preferencesScreen);
        newClass.frame.pack();
        newClass.frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        newClass.frame.setVisible(true);
        newClass.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }


    JPanel preferencesScreen;
    JButton backButton;
    JSlider slider;
    JComboBox<String> restrictionDropdown;
    String[] allergies = new String[] {"Dust", "Oak"};
    ActionListener actionListener;
    JFrame frame;

    // method name should describe actions ("showPreferencesScreen", etc), not objects
    public void preferencesScreen() {

        // variable name is same as method name -- confusing...
        preferencesScreen = new JPanel();
        preferencesScreen.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
//        preferencesScreen.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 1000);

        backButton = new JButton("<-");
        slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 100, 50);

        //restrictionDropdown = new JComboBox<>(user.getPreferences().allergies);
        restrictionDropdown = new JComboBox<>(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(allergies));
        restrictionDropdown.setLocation(200, 300);
        restrictionDropdown.setSize(100, 100);
        restrictionDropdown.addActionListener(actionListener);
        restrictionDropdown.setEditable(true);
        preferencesScreen.add(restrictionDropdown);

        slider.setMajorTickSpacing(5);
        slider.setPaintTicks(true);

        backButton.setBounds(20, 30, 50, 40);
        slider.setBounds(300, 140, 160, 50);

        backButton.addActionListener(actionListener);

        preferencesScreen.add(backButton);
        preferencesScreen.add(slider);

        //frame.setVisible(true); // you don't want this here
    }
}
```

(notice the code is copy/paste executable -- just create a NewClass1.java file, paste the code, and run -- makes it easy to communicate these problems/solutions).

That code produces this:

[image]

Not sure if that's what you were looking for.

A few notes:

1. Don't use a `null` Layout. I used `FlowLayout` to keep your example very simple, but if I'm looking to make a quick UI I almost always use Netbeans 8.2's Swing UI builder (which uses `AbsoluteLayout` but auto-generates the layout code. (what you see in this pic took 10 seconds literally)
   [image]
2. Check my other comments for some suggestions on how you can improve.
3. Swing is great (my favorite UI tool), but it's old and on its way out. So use it to learn but don't make production applications with it.